# Prevent text to overrun inside modal

Tags: jquery, datatables, bootstrap-modal

I have an issue regarding about modal when a table data contain huge texts it will overrun outside. I also used datatables from [here.](https://datatables.net/)

See Image below:

[image]

I know I can move the long text to new ling by using `word-wrap:break-word;` but how can I add the class? Also Is there a way I can change the modal size?

Code that displays the modal:

```
responsive: {
   details: {
    display: $.fn.dataTable.Responsive.display.modal( {
        header: function ( row ) {
            var data = row.data();
            return 'Details for '+data['first_name']+' '+data['last_name'];
        }
    } ),
    renderer: $.fn.dataTable.Responsive.renderer.tableAll({
     tableClass: 'table'
    })
   }
  }
```

fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/qwqLnk7n/)

Comment: Could you add a fiddle?

Comment: If you can use html in modal Use html **a** tag. @claudios

Comment: I can't use html in modal coz it's generated by jquery

Comment: OP, inspect the element and find out it's selector.. then in your css, write `element {white-space: normal; }`. That should take care of the problem.

Comment: try to use modal-md or modal-lg if not try to return table data displayOptions with html element

Comment: Note: I can't add classes directly because the modal is generated by the `display method`

Comment: can't you listen to and handle the modal open event and add the class by the reference using jquery ?

Comment: @BlackBurn027, as of now I'm working around this issue.

Comment: Please add jsfiddle and plunker so, we can take a look at the codes.

Comment: added fiddle. please check

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
.modal-body table
{
  table-layout: fixed;
}

.modal-body table td
{
  word-wrap:break-word
}
```

**UPDATED**

I add class called **myDetailClass**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#example').DataTable( {
    responsive: {
        details: {
            display: $.fn.dataTable.Responsive.display.modal( {
                header: function ( row ) {
                    var data = row.data();
                    return 'Details for '+data[0]+' '+data[1];
                }
            } ),
            renderer: $.fn.dataTable.Responsive.renderer.tableAll( {
                tableClass: 'table myDetailClass'
            } )
        }
    }
    } );
} );
```

then

```
.myDetailClass
{
  table-layout: fixed;
  word-wrap:break-word;
}
```

You can also make custom modal. Detail is [here](https://datatables.net/reference/option/responsive.details.renderer)

Comment: heey, Thanks for this and it did solve just what I wanted but how can I add specific class to that modal so that other modals won't be affected?

Answer (score 3):

You can access the item by selecting the path in the generated modal's table like this (according to the similar example on the [DataTables website](https://datatables.net/extensions/responsive/examples/display-types/bootstrap-modal.html)):

```
.modal-body > table > tbody > tr:last-child > td:last-child {
    overflow-wrap: break-words;
}
```

With `break-words` it would show the data on more than one line. Another option would be to simply hide the overflowing part

```
.modal-body > table > tbody > tr:last-child > td:last-child {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Or have it automatically shorten and add an `...` ellipsis to the string.

```
.modal-body > table > tbody > tr:last-child > td:last-child {
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

To make the modal wider, you can select for

```
.modal-dialog {
    width: 90vw;
}
```

That makes the model 90% of the screen width and centers it.

Add these `<style>`s *after* the import `<link>` for Bootstrap, so it doesn't get overwritten by the imported styles.

---

To play with the properties yourself, go to your table and open a modal. Then right click it and (in Chrome/Chromium) select *Inspect*.

You can edit the style properties directly in the live HTML of the *Inspect* view. Right click an element in the HTML and select *"Add Attribute"* to add the `style` attribute and give it the style you want to test.

Comment: This also worked for me but I wanted to add a class where I can put my style to override the modal so that other modals won't be affected.